# display all store id and store name in custom admin module

Tags: magento-1.8

I am new to the Magento and i am using Magento 1.8.

I am creating custom admin module that need to be display all the store id and store names in grid as like product grid.

I have created grid and everything working fine but, While displaying id and name in grid, I am not able to only store id and store name.

My Prepare collection function is as follow:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
 $store = $this->_getStore();
 $collection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection();
 $this->setCollection($collection);
 parent::_prepareCollection();
 return $this;
}
```

And my prepare column function is

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('foundation')->__('storeid'),
                'index' => 'store_id',
                'type' => 'store',
                'width' => '100px',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
            $this->addColumn('store_name', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('foundation')->__('store name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'type' => 'store',
                'width' => '100px',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

Now I am getting result as follow
[image]

How can I display only store id and store name in the grid?
Help me friends, I am new to the Magento.
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
        $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('foundation')->__('storeid'),
            'index' => 'store_id',
            'type' => 'number',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('store_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('foundation')->__('store name'),
            'index' => 'name',
        ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Comment: Marius Thank you.. The answer is exactly done the work as I needed. You Rocks dude, Thanks a lot.. I searching it from 2 hours.. Thanks

Comment: Marius!!.. I am getting store-view id and store-view name...How can I get store id and name not store-veiw???

Comment: @Charlie Instead of `$collection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection();` use `$collection = Mage::getModel('core/store_group')->getCollection();`

Comment: Yeah thanks once again @Marius.. the store id field name may differ here?? I am not understand this flow. I mean prepare collection and prepare column function relation. can you explain me or can you send any links that may help me to understand the these two function and database relation??

Comment: yeah...if you change the collection class then you might need to change the grid column index. The index must be the same as the table column that holds the value you need. I don't have any links, sorry. You can dig into how admin grids work in the code.